# android studio - change font in all Text View in View Pager

Tags: android, fonts, android-viewpager

I have ViewPager who include four layouts (each other is the same: ImageView and two TextViews control):

```
view_pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

layouts = new int[] {
            R.layout.activity_screen_walk_1,
            R.layout.activity_screen_walk_2,
            R.layout.activity_screen_walk_3,
            R.layout.activity_screen_walk_4
        };

viewPageAdapter = new ViewPageAdapter();
view_pager.setAdapter(viewPageAdapter);
view_pager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);
```

This code it ok - view pager is displayed and workong fine. But I want change font in all Text Views in layouts in view pager.

```
Typeface myFontBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Oswald-Bold.ttf");


for (int count=0; count < view_pager.getChildCount(); count++){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ppp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    View view = view_pager.getChildAt(count);
    if(view instanceof TextView){
        ((TextView)view).setTypeface(myFontBold);
    }
}
```

But this dosn't work...
Help me, please.
Regards
Marcin

Answer (score 0):

Here, `View view = view_pager.getChildAt(count);` the view returned is your whole layout.

So, try this to set the font for the TextView:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.<your TextView ID>);
tv.setTypeface(myFontBold);
```